# Storing date as time in millis

Tags: date, time

I try to represent date objects in a data storage without the hassle of Date object in Java. So I thought of using just a time in milliseconds and store the UTC time zone as well. I thought about using simple shift routines to combine everything in a single long as time zone is just 5bits (+/-12).

Can someone see any problem with this? What other compact storage schemes (other than textual representation) of date exist and how do they compare to this?

Comment: Nepal's time zone is UTC + 5:45. Phoenix island is UTC + 13. How do these fit into your +/- 12 plan?

Comment: In *general*, if your data storage mechanism (you haven't identified what you're using) has a data type *designed* for storing date/time data, then there's probably already a mapping from Java `Date`s into that form, that handles any translation nuances. Try to *avoid* strings (since using strings then *introduces* formatting issues)

Comment: UTC standards says -12 to +14 so having 5bits (-16/+15) would be enough but the quaterly offset is interesting so its 7 so for ease it becomes 8 bits. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're under valuing granularity in your time zone and over valuing the need for bits in the timestamp.

A long has has 8 bytes for this purpose.

Lets say you allow yourself 2 bytes for the time zone.  That leaves you with 6 for the timestamp.  6*8 = 48 bits for a timestamp.

The largest number a 48 bit unsigned integer can handle is 281474976710655.

Divide by 1000 to get from miliseconds to seconds 281474976710

Punch that number into an [epoch converter](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php): 10889-08-02T05:31:50+00:00

That's the year 10,889 when we're in 2,015.

Just use 2 bytes for the timezone.  You've got the space.  That will easily allow you to represent the timezone as minutes offset +-24 hours. And since it's whole bytes, the packing code will be simpler to comprehend.

Comment: I also did a calculation with 8 bits and got 1142465 years in both directions. So you are right. The problem would be daylight saving time and stuff but this is depending on the country and something that is out of context.

Comment: Yeah  countries with daylight savings shift their timezone from one part of the year to the other.  Eg: the UK shifts between UTC+0 (winter) and UTC+1 (summer).